# sqlcmd runs fine and cmd line but will not produce output as a exec cmd step in a SQL Agent job

Tags: cmd, sql-server-2014, sqlcmd

I am pulling my hair out and have tried every posting suggest.

I have a tsql script called C:\DBAReports\testsql.sql.  If I go to a command logged prompt on my server, and run: `sqlcmd -S localhost -i C:\DBAReports\testsql.sql -o C:\DBAReports\testout.txt`

But if I create an new agent job with 1 step of type Operating system (CmdExec) to run as a SQL Server Agent Service Account, On Success Quit the job reporting success and on Failure Quit the job reporting failure. with the owner my same admin windows login as when I run the cmd prompt, right click on the agent job and start at step 1, I get the job succeeded (Job was invoked by my windows login), and the Step 1 is Executed as user is-sql "The step did not generate any output.  Process Exit Code 0.  The step was successful".

But it doesn't write the output file.

Any ideas?

The reason I want to do this is I am getting periodic Error: 18057, Severity: 20, State: 2 Failed to set up execution content in my sql server log.  What I hope to do is kick off this job when this occurs to try and find out what are the SPIDs, status, SQL running, etc and write it to an output file.

My testsql.sql script contains.

```
SELECT
    SPID                = er.session_id
    ,STATUS             = ses.STATUS
    ,[Login]            = ses.login_name
    ,Host               = ses.host_name
    ,BlkBy              = er.blocking_session_id
    ,DBName             = DB_Name(er.database_id)
,CommandType        = er.command
,SQLStatement       = st.text
,ObjectName         = OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid)
,ElapsedMS          = er.total_elapsed_time
,CPUTime            = er.cpu_time
,IOReads            = er.logical_reads + er.reads
,IOWrites           = er.writes
,LastWaitType       = er.last_wait_type
,StartTime          = er.start_time
,Protocol           = con.net_transport
,ConnectionWrites   = con.num_writes
,ConnectionReads    = con.num_reads
,ClientAddress      = con.client_net_address
,Authentication     = con.auth_scheme
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests er
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(er.sql_handle) st
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions ses
ON ses.session_id = er.session_id
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections con
ON con.session_id = ses.session_id
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I have tried so many suggestions, and either get syntax errors on the command, and when I don't get any syntax error on the sqlcmd, it just generates no output.

Comment: Your second paragraph is incomplete... what happens exactly if you run the `sqlcmd` in command-line? Please edit your question and complete that sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  If I run sqlcmd -S localhost -i C:\DBAReports\testsql.sql -o C:\DBAReports\testout.txt in the command line, it works.  In other words, it runs the testsql.sql script and produces the output for the sql in a file called testout.txt  I am thinking there must be something about the permissions when trying to run this as an agent job.  I am new to sql server.  I ended up working around it with a stored procedure, but still would like to get the commandline working.

Comment: Can you take a look at the Login properties of the Login use to execute the job? Look at the Server Roles of the Login: does it have `diskadmin` or `serveradmin` roles? Note that I'm not too proficient with jobs and such. But it could be that the Login doesn't have the proper Server Roles.

Comment: Perhaps you could run the job AS a Windows Account with System Administrator role?

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way - try modifying the job step as Type: `T-SQL` script and the command as:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'C:\Work\temp\test3.bat'
```

Please replace the bat file path with yours.